# Dropping requests for blacklisted / banned users

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a RESTful service, where almost all endpoints have a url parameter `userId`.

I have a separate DynamoDB table storing users that are blacklisted, and want all requests by any of these users to be dropped (i.e. return a 401 code), and otherwise proceed.

My approach to this is to implement and register a `OncePerRequestFilter` as beans, but I'm not 100% sure how to implement this (within the `doFilterInternal`), or if there is a better way to implement this.

What I have so far:

```
public class BlacklistedFilter extended OncePerRequestFilter {
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "banned-users";
    // Instantiate dynamo connection with some service provider
    this.dynamoService = new dynamoService('TABLE_NAME');


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Retrieve path variable `userId`
        final Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
        final String userId = pathVariables.get('userId');

        Item item = this.dynamoService.getUser(userId);
        // This is doing: dynamoClient.getTable(TABLE_NAME).getItem('userId', userId)

        // What do I do here????
        if (item != null) {
            // Proceed to original request
        } else {
            // RETURN 401
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have Spring Security in your stack? If not, Spring Web @MVC supports interceptors for request handlers too!

Answer (score 0):

If it works than it is good enough. You can create separate method. And [cache](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial) the result if they do not change to often.

```java
@Cacheable("isBlacklisted")
public boolean isBlacklisted(String userId) {
  Item item = this.dynamoService.getUser(userId);
  return item != null;
}
```